# How to run java/javac command from terminal

Tags: java, jdk

I have installed jdk using .deb(convert from rpm),but i can't run java/javac command from terminal.

Comment: "but i can't run java/javac command from terminal" ... "why not?" is going to be the question you need to answer 1st.

Comment: Could I recommend that you try the Ubuntu packages instead? sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk would get you an equivalent environment and simply issuing a "java" command from the command line would work. For more info, look here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java

Answer (score 0):

To find where java was installed do:

```
find / -name "*java" -type f 2> /dev/null
```

Look for something like: /usr/java/jdk.../bin/javac or /usr/java/jre..../bin/java.

Then run the command with the full path:

```
/usr/java/jre.../bin/java
```